# Wordpress at hover change the featured Image

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

i using the portfolio-theme studio 9 from simon bouchard. 
A great theme with powerfull options.`http://themes.simonbouchard.com/studio9/works/`

now i would like to change the view of the work-section. 
the featured image should change at hovering.

i search fpr the term and found a lot of stuff but always very special and i don´t know to code it in my theme. i´m not good at php or java.

my idea is to work with custom fields and to add a line of code that the image change to the custom field at hovering. i hope it is so simple and you can help me to fix the problem.

thank you so much!

i saw the effect at this page `http://heydays.no` and found it very very fresh.

Answer (score 1):

The site you like uses ajax to cycle through multiple images when the block is hovered. Your theme probably does not support that. I suggest you look for a theme or plugin that offers the effect you want out-of-the-box. [This one](http://demo.spnoy.com/nikka/) comes close and you may be able to set it to do a complete image switch instead of an effect. But the effects actually look cooler to me than the image switch.